# Error No word from the language model has pronunciation in the dictionary

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to develop an android app that recognize some command with cmusphinx. Cmusphinx works well however dictionary that it uses has too much vocabulary that I don't need. What I did is creating a new dictionary with [imtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html) and adding it into PocketSphinxAndroidDemo. At the end I got an error

```
01-20 11:14:34.492: E/cmusphinx(3586): ERROR: "ngram_search_fwdtree.c", line 336: No word from the language model has pronunciation in the dictionary
```

What may cause this error ? Should I change anything else in order to add a new dictionary into the project? I checked official documentation but could not find any information about it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the set of words in the dictionary doesn't match the set of words in the language model. Dictionary has `.dic` or `.dict` extension and is located in assets folder of PocketsphinxAndroid project. Language model has `.lm` or `.dmp` extension and is located in assets folder too.

You can open both files with a text editor and compare the vocabulary in dictionary and language model. Those should match. Take into account that both are case-sensitive so if dictionary is in lowercase the language model should be in lowercase too.

Most likely reason is case mismatch or encoding mismatch.

Comment: I missed to delete weather.dmp file which is defaultly added into sample project. When I remove lines which contain weather.dmp, application starts working. Thanks for your answer